# #ifdef works for Windows+MSVC, fails for Cygwin64+gcc - why?

Tags: gcc, cygwin, environment-variables, c-preprocessor

I'm using the following code in a library I'm working on:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && ! defined(__BORLANDC__)
    _putenv("PO_TEST_FOO=1");
#else
    putenv(const_cast<char*>("PO_TEST_FOO=1"));
#endif
```

and this works with Windows+MSVC and with Linux+GCC (and Linux+clang and so on). But - it [fails](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/vprus/program-options/build/1.0.30-develop/job/lorsed146c2hke9j) with Cygwin64 and GCC (link to an appveyor build log; GCC version is v6.4.0).

1. Why does it fail?
2. Is it really supposed to fail, i.e. is it my fault?
3. How do I make sure it doesn't (without breaking other things)?

Comment: `_WIN32` is not defined on Cygwin. `putenv` is available https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/compatibility.html#std-susv4  . http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html

Comment: @matzeri: Well, I have some Appveyor builds with Cygwin64 which claim otherwise... they break with `putenv()` bur work with `_putenv()`.

Comment: @matzeri: Wait, maybe you're right and it's actually mingw rather than Cygwin. I'll check.

Comment: Did you include the appropriate headers? Such as `stdlib.h`? Also, you don't need the cast. In fact, that type of cast is likely to mask bugs.

Comment: @KurtisRader: 1. Actually, I only have `<cstdlib>`. 2. It's not my code, so I haven't touched that, but it sounds like you're right.